# Regex for clean URLs

Tags: regex, lighttpd

Clean URLs seem pretty simple but I'm in need of a special situation. I would like to be able to include the .html suffix or nothing at all but not any other extension:

```
someurl = pass
someurl/somepage = pass
someurl.html = pass
someurl/somepage.html = pass

someurl.css = fail
someurl.exe = fail
someurl.anyotherextension = fail
someurl/someother.ext = fail
```

Is this possible? Would I have to somehow exclude the extensions I don't want?

Edit:

None of the answers so far seem to work. The only thing that I've discovered on my own that works is:

```
^/([\w]*(.html)?)$
```

but it will not work with slashes in the url. Adding a slash inside the character class brackets makes it fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex option for clean URLs with .html extension option:

```
^/([\w\/]*(\.html)?)$
```

Full lighttpd.conf line:

```
url.rewrite = ( "^/([\w\/]*(\.html)?)$" => "index.php?page=$1" )
```

Quick reminder: Absolute paths to files or a base href should be implemented in any pages that pass this regex.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?:^|/)[^./]+(?:\.html)?$
```

Translation: starting from the last `/` if there is one (or from the beginning of the string if not) match one or more of anything except `/` or `.`, optionally terminated by `.html`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\.html$|(?:^|.*\/)[^\.]+$/
```

ending with ".html" or have no "." from the beginning of the url or the last / to the end (you can have folders containing a ".")

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
(^[^\.]+?$)|(^.+?\.html$)
```

This matches either a string that doesn't contain any `.` or a string that ends with `.html`.

Or use this, if you want to use dots in your "folder" names:

```
(^.+?/[^\.]+?$)|(^.+?\.html$)
```

Matches either a string that contains no `.` after the last `/` or a string that ends with `.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use a regex to match the URLs you want to allow (as the other answers seem to try), use a regex to match the URLs that you want to block:

```
\.(?!html$)[^./]*$
```

This regex matches the extension of a URL, unless the extension is `.html`.  URLs without an extension or an `.html` extension are not matched.  Your examples don't include URLs with queries (`?param=value`) or fragements (`#anchor`) so the regex does not account for those.  I'm also assuming your regex flavor supports [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).